# Codeigniter language change language in view

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

My Codeigniter site uses the language classes of CodeIgniter with their corresponding language files.
My view has 3 links on top to change the language. But how do I create these links?
When I'm on page domain.com/nl/home, my language should appear like this

```
domain.com/en/home
domain.com/de/home
domein.com/fr/home
```

I also want to add a css class to currently used language.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need for the language to appear in the url. It is hard to maintain if the site grows bigger. You can use something like this is a controller (or a hook if you use this in multiple controllers)

```
/* BEGIN Language settings */
    $lang_array=array('english','spanish');

    if(!$this->session->userdata('language')){
           self::$current_language =  $this->config->item('language');
           $this->session->set_userdata('language', self::$current_language);
    }else{
           self::$current_language = $this->session->userdata('language');
    }
    // Css purpose
    $this->page_data['display_en'] = "";
    $this->page_data['display_sp'] = "";
    switch(self::$current_language){
        case 'english':$this->page_data['display_en'] = "display:none";break;
        case 'spanish':$this->page_data['display_sp'] = "display:none";break;
    }
   // Load language files
   $this->lang->load('profile',  self::$current_language);
   $this->lang->load('products',  self::$current_language);

   $this->page_data['page_lang'] = self::$current_language;
   // Abbreviated language name
   $this->page_data['lang'] = substr(self::$current_language,0,2);

   /* END Language settings */
```